# Hide table row if every cell except first contains a space/is empty

Tags: javascript, html-table

I have a table that is filled from a CSV file into GridView. There is a header column and row. Some of the rows are empty except for the first column, which has a category. I am trying to create a condition in javascript where if the row is blank (except for the first cell), then the row is hidden.

```
$('tr:not(:first-child)').each(function () {

                let rowData = new Array();
                var q = 0;

                $(this).find('td:not(:first-child)').each(function () {

                    rowData[q++] = $(this).text();

                });

                let result = rowData.every(function (val) {

                    return val == " "

                });

                if (result == true) {
                    // hide row
                };
            });
```

When I debug the array, the value for `rowData` I want to return true is `[ , , , , , , ]` and each value in the array is `" "` Any suggestions?  Thanks.

**Update:**

This code works:

```
            $('tr:not(:first-child)').each(function () {
                let rowData = new Array();
                var q = 0;
                $(this).find('td:not(:first-child)').each(function () {
                    rowData[q++] = $(this).text();
                });
                let result = rowData.every(function (val) {
                    return String(val).trim() === ""
                });
                if (result == true) {
                    $(this).closest('tr').hide();
                };
            });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By checking with `val == " "` you only check if the string contains 1 empty string.

You can use `jQuery.map()` function to map the elements and use `.get()` function to get mapped values as array.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  let result = $('div.my-div:not(:first-of-type)')
    .map(function() {
      return $(this).text()
    })
    .get()
    .every(function(val) {
      return String(val).trim() === ""
    });


  console.log(result)
})
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.1.min.js"></script>

<div class="my-div">1</div>
<div class="my-div">&nbsp;</div>
<div class="my-div"> </div>
<div class="my-div"> </div>
<div class="my-div"></div>
<div class="my-div"></div>
```

Comment: I was having trouble using map and get to come up true as well, but when i added `String(val).trim() === ""` it worked, so thanks! I'll update my code above.  Side note: Doesn't .every() check each string in the array against the function?